# Spring Data REST with custom GSON instance

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gson, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am trying to use GSON for JSON (de)serialization in my entire project. Access to the database is handled by a Spring Data REST service.
The Spring Boot version is `1.5.3.RELEASE`.
I need to use a custom GSON instance but Jackson appears to obstruct the way.

The dependencies declared in my `pom.xml` are as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have registered a custom type adapter for handling JodaTime-based DateTime instances.

```
@Bean
public Gson gson() {
    return new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(DateTime.class, new JodaDateTimeAdapter())
            .create();
}
```

Also I set `spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson`.
This setup works just fine with requests and responses on a 
`@RestController` (Tested with a request mapping that pings back the exact same object that it received.). However, the REST interface of my repositories (`@RepositoryRestResource` from `spring-boot-starter-data-rest`) is still using Jackson (send the same POST request for an entity as before):

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON document: Can not construct instance of org.joda.time.DateTime: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2017-05-29T20:31:57.898+02:00')
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@36d7b26; line: 10, column: 19] (through reference chain: cc.backend.model.database.DeviceDB["device"]->cc.model.Device["lastUpdate"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.joda.time.DateTime: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2017-05-29T20:31:57.898+02:00')
at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@36d7b26; line: 10, column: 19] (through reference chain: cc.backend.model.database.DeviceDB["device"]->cc.model.Device["lastUpdate"])
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:234) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:211) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:193) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.read(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:236) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.read(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:193) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.java:141) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
```

Comment: Refer https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/023-configure-integrate-gson-spring-boot/, it might help you

Comment: Thank you but that is exactly where I took the different approaches from.

Comment: I rephrased the question as GSON operates nicely with `@RestController` but not with `@RepositoryRestResource`

Comment: According to [Spring Data REST - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.custom-jackson-deserialization), we can only customize Jackson, but there is no mention of Gson. Hope somebody could answer: if we could use Spring Data REST with Gson instead of Jackson